# Can only boot in recovery mode and resuming normal boot, but then Ubuntu gets very slow after resuming normal boot

Tags: boot

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04(Ubuntu only no windows) and I'm not able to do a normal boot, screen freezes. I have to go to recovery mode and then "resume normal boot" to start Ubuntu. That would not be a big problem but I suspect that resuming normal boot after booting in recovery mode causes the interface to be very slow and laggy. When resuming normal boot, Ubuntu warns that "some graphic drivers require a full graphical boot and so will fail when resuming from recovery." So that's why I'm assuming this is the cause of the interface being slow.

I already tried "nomodeset" that I read in other questions but that did nothing.

Specs:
Intel® Atom™ N470 (1.83GHz)
Intel® NM10 Express Chipset
Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150

SO do I have to install specific drivers for this video card?

Could it be that the lack of a proper driver is preventing Ubuntu from booting?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine replacing `quit splash` with `nomodeset` and adding a delay to your ligtdm or sddm worked for me in a similar situation.