# Ubuntu will not start

Tags: 14.04, boot, unity

Ubuntu 14.04 will not start. I can get is far as the Grub menu but when I select Ubuntu I immediately get a black screen and nothing happens. I can boot normally when I use an older Linux version but unity will not work. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Does it boot if you go through the recovery menu? If so, see my post here:
[NVidia driver, normal boot results in blank screen, recovery boot works fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine)