# Freeze after normal login, works fine if recovery mode

Tags: boot, 16.04

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a completely new machine delivered without OS. I installed Windows 10 first, and then Ubuntu for dual-booting.

However, when I boot up Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, I get to type in my password, and then 1-2 seconds after hitting enter the screen freezes indefinitely and only forcing a shutdown will make the computer do anything at all.

However, if I choose advanced options and boot in recovery mode and resume normal boot, then when I log in everything shows up as normal after 4-5 seconds of nothing but the background image.

So I'm guessing something is wrong with my Ubuntu install, which makes sense, considering the "restart now" option at the end of the install wizard bugged out and made me restart manually with a forced shutdown.

Anyone know what this is, or how I can go about fixing it?

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine replacing `quit splash` with `nomodeset` and adding a delay to your ligtdm or sddm worked for me in a similar situation.

Comment: had the same problem with 18.10. nomodeset worked.