# normal boot hangs, recovery mode works

Tags: boot, grub2

When trying to boot normally from grub I get a black screen when it should be showing me the password field for my boot partition. Entering the password anyway does not boot Ubuntu.

When I delete `quiet splash` from the boot options then the last line I can see is about EHCI, but no errors are visible. At that point the boot process hangs and the only thing that I can do is reboot with CTRL+ALT+DEL.

Booting with the recovery mode works as expected. The dialog asking for the root partition password appears and everything works as expected after I select the resume option twice.

I tried running boot repair and get this paste from it: http://paste2.org/CVcxaMpp

The BIOS is set to boot from the correct disk /dev/sda

I have recently upgraded my graphic card from an old nvidia to a newer nvidia card, but I am not sure that the problems started at that point.

I have tried to swap my keyboard and mouse before booting to rule out that they are the problem. This didn't change anything.

I have tried to disconnect all disks besides the main ubuntu disk, but that didn't help either.

Changing the boot options from `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` and adding a delay to /etc/init.d/sddm

```
# Wait for plymouth if running
[ -x /bin/plymouth ] && /bin/plymouth quit
sleep 2
call do_start_cmd
```

just let me boot almost normal. Doing only one of these does not work. Unfortunately I don't get a nice looking boot process when I remove `quiet splash`.

Comment: Your new Nvidia card most likely needs nvidia proprietary drivers. Edit the boot options and use `nomodeset` instead. This will give you generic Vesa video so you can install the recommended drivers for your new card. It has nothing to do with bootloaders.

Comment: The newest nvidia drivers are already installed. Although I did not install them after the graphic card upgrade. `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` does not install any additional drivers.

Comment: My question seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine

Comment: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` does help