# Ubuntu 20.04: Normal boot works, recovery mode hangs

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kernel, luks, recovery-mode

Most of the related questions here are about normal boot not working properly, but recovery mode working.
In my case it's the other way around.

I'm running a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 with LUKS. Grub has not caused me any problems, and allows me to boot normally to both systems, as well as access the UEFI firmware.

The problem arises when I select "Advanced options" in the grub menu, and then recovery mode for the newest kernel I have installed: I have both `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic` and `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-41-generic`.

To summarize:

- If I boot with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic`, it works properly
- If I boot with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-42-generic (recovery mode)`, insert the LUKS password, and then select `resume` to proceed with a normal boot, it works properly
- If I boot with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-41-generic`, it works properly
- If I boot with `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-41-generic (recovery mode)`, insert the LUKS password, and then select `resume` to proceed with a normal boot, it freezes on a black screen with an underscore on the top left, see [image: this]

---

I have tried the fixes described in this related question: [NVidia driver, normal boot results in blank screen, recovery boot works fine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527356/nvidia-driver-normal-boot-results-in-blank-screen-recovery-boot-works-fine?noredirect=1&lq=1), meaning

- adding `nomodeset` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in `/etc/default/grub` [(here)](https://askubuntu.com/a/527370)
- adding a short delay before my display manager starts [(here)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253798)

None of them work (in fact they just make it worse by breaking normal boots).

---

Please let me know if you require snippets of config files from `/etc` or `/boot`.

I would sincerely appreciate any form of assistance.
This is not an urgent issue, however a future kernel update might make the problem bigger by silently breaking recovery mode entirely.